# Smooth lerping through list of vector3's

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using GameLift, so I don't think I can use Unity's network tools, so I am writing my own `NetworkTransform` like component. This works, where on the client when I move the character the character moves on the server.

On the server which currently just mimics the client, the player moves somewhat jerky. How can I smooth out my lerp as I move through the list? It looks as if the jerky part is when it goes from one list item to another.

```
private List<Vector3> syncPosList = new List<Vector3>();

public float interpolationFactor = 18;
public float interpolationFactorFaster = 25;

public void OnNetworkMessage(Vector3 v3) {
  syncPosList.Add(v3);
}

void Update() {
  ListLerp();
}

void ListLerp() {
  if (syncPosList.Count > 0) {
    var speed = syncPosList.Count > 1 ? interpolationFactorFaster : interpolationFactor;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, syncPosList[0], Time.deltaTime * interpolationFactor);
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, syncPosList[0]) < 0.1f) {
      syncPosList.RemoveAt(0);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Movement]

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? The motion model you have right now is a bit weird. It could be described as a spring that is attached to the model and the first entry in the list, such that it pulls the model towards the target point. And if it is close enough, the target point suddenly changes. Is this what you mean by *jerky*? What kind of motion do you want?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right. I would like it to transition from one point to another smoothly. I am assuming it is **jerky** because of the `distance` method. That lerp i got from a youtube video https://youtu.be/mIeQhEhi1QQ?t=981 so maybe there is a better way...

Comment: Smooth is a tricky word, it can be understood on many levels. I guess you mean that the motion is physically plausible. For this, you would need continuous velocity vectors (C1 continuity) and I would even suggest continuous acceleration vectors (C2 continuity). Are you thinking of something like a motion along a [B-spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline)? Or are the positions coming in at a high frequency and you just want to blend into them?

Comment: I have added a gif, as you can see as it moves, it periodically jumps a little.

Comment: Ok, I see. I wouldn't keep the full path but only the current position. After all, the client is telling you, "The current position is x". If you start going through the entire history, you may just fall behind in time. Maybe, you could use your lerping strategy with the most recently received position? You can also try to make this continuous by just altering the objects velocity.

Comment: If I did it correctly `Vector3.Lerp(syncPosList[0], syncPosList[1], ...)` it doesn't seem to work. The network player just moves back and forth about 1/4 of a unit.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure if on your client side things are handled through the Unity physics engine which is why you are not experiencing the jerk you see through your client; however, you can somewhat think of your server handling everything kinematically since it appears you are just overriding the position of the players and trying to linearly interpolate to the next position.

This is not the approach I would take but if you are set on doing this, I would start by recommending you change your Update function to FixedUpdate:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    ListLerp();
}
```

If you do this I believe that you shouldn't even need linear interpolation, just change the position of the player to the Vector that the packet has sent and as long as your client-server connection is good along with your packet send rate, there shouldn't be a substantial difference between the position of your player at any point in time.

Comment: I am not using physics, I am using the character controller. With this movement script https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Ah okay. Do you know what happens when you just set the position in OnNetworkMessage() instead of interpolating to the position. I have a feeling that interpolating might be causing the object to lag behind the actual character and as the velocity increases, I can imagine so will the stutter.

Comment: If I just set it, it jumps to the position, its not as smooth. If I just use a vector instead of a list of vectors, that seems to work fairly well..